# Why Windows output redirection does not work in ant <exec>

Tags: xml, ant

I am trying to execute `cmd.exe /C echo Please write this to a file >> output.txt` using ant `<exec>` task. This command works fine when executed from command line. But does not work when executed using ant. Here is what I am trying to do.

```
 <exec executable="${env.ComSpec}" osfamily="windows">
    <arg value="/C"/>
    <arg value="echo"/>
    <arg value="Please write this to file"/>
    <arg value=">>"/>
    <arg value="output.txt"/>
</exec>
```

Can somebody tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `>>` is not an argument to `cmd.exe` you are about to execute, but to the current shell

Try the `output` parameter of the [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) ant task

```
<exec executable="${env.ComSpec}" osfamily="windows" output="output.txt"> 
  <arg value="/C"/> 
  <arg value="echo"/> 
  <arg value="Please write this to file"/> 
</exec>
```